# SmtpClient shadows exceptions if timeout is enabled

Tags: c#, .net, smtpclient

Is this a bug in the .NET Framework and if so how do I report it, because everywhere I can report bugs I always get an "not authorized" error, so right now I'm just like meh.

Anyway the issue is that `SmtpClient` will shadow any exceptions thrown, if `timeOut` is enabled, unless it's `SmtpFailedRecipientException` and not fatal.

You can see it in the code here:
http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/mail/SmtpClient.cs,538

```
catch (Exception e) {
    if (Logging.On) Logging.Exception(Logging.Web, this, "Send", e);

    if (e is SmtpFailedRecipientException && !((SmtpFailedRecipientException)e).fatal) {
        throw;
    }


    Abort();
    // This is the issue ... As you can see when timout is enabled, a timeout exception is thrown no matter what
    if (timedOut) {
        throw new SmtpException(SR.GetString(SR.net_timeout));
    }

    if (e is SecurityException ||
        e is AuthenticationException ||
        e is SmtpException) 
    {
        throw;
    }

    throw new SmtpException(SR.GetString(SR.SmtpSendMailFailure), e);
}
```

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/mail/SmtpClient.cs,680

(Same as above, but in `SendAsync`.)

If it's not a bug, could someone give me the exact reason why the behavior is as such? Right now it causes mails to be seen as errors because of timeouts, but in reality they have actually been sent and there is no way to figure out what the actual error is. If it is however a bug, how can I report it when I always get an `Not authorized` error every time I try to create a feedback.

Comment: Why do you say an email has actually been sent, when the timeout has occurred?  Yes, the email server might have actually received the email, and might be processing it, but hasn't responded in a timely manner, and therefore the timeout happens and the exception is thrown.

Comment: The email has been successfully sent before the timeout and something causes it to linger, but I have no way of telling what because timeouts shadows whatever exceptions are thrown. I will mind you I do not have access to modify any usage of it and thus I cannot do anything to work around it

Comment: OK, so the problem is with your email server, not the .net code?

Comment: No the problem is I don't get an inner exception, just because timeout is enabled

Comment: Still trying to get my head around the problem.  When ANY exception is thrown AND the timeout has occurred, it's ALWAYS treated as a timeout exception with no reference to the actual exception (which MIGHT not have been a timeout).  Is that a correct reading of the code?

Comment: Yes, that is correct